# error retrieving items containg spaces from javascript array

Tags: html, arrays

I'm trying to retrieve data from jquery array and this data contains spaces between texts, I push data like this

```
selected_name.push("test data");
```

but when I try to retrieve it back I log it into console like that

```
console.log(selected_name[0]);
```

I only get `test` not `test data`, I need to retrieve the whole string.

**Edit:**

I'm actually retrieving value that I push to array from an html checkbox's value which is set like that:

```
var chk="<td><input type='checkbox' class="+item.location_name+" id="+item.items_id+" value="+item.items_name+" onchange='check(this.id, this.value, this.className)'/></td>";
```

but when I try to retrieve the value I only get first word if the string contains spaces.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. I'll bet the problem is in the code that's pushing onto the array, it's not really pushing the whole string. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: As @Barmar said, it is probably not pushing "test data", I couldn't reproduce your problem [in this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qt5dLtz1/)

Comment: Please have another look on my question....I edited it.

Comment: It should be the same answer.  Nothing inherent with push() splits a string by space before adding it to an array.

Comment: Side note, "error retrieving items containg spaces from jquery array".  None of this is jquery.  It's all javascript.

Comment: thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't quote the checkbox value. So the HTML ends up being:

```
<input ... value=test data onchange='check(this.id, this.value, this.className)'/>
```

Since there are no quotes around the value, it only uses `test` as the value, and `data` is a different attribute. You should always quote all attributes to avoid problems like this.

```
var chk="<td><input type='checkbox' class='"+item.location_name+"' id='"+item.items_id+"' value='"+item.items_name+"' onchange='check(this.id, this.value, this.className)'/></td>";
```